# Using preg_match() or other preg func to get number after hyphen from a string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have like Employee Code like this

```
EMP-0006
```

How can I get numbers after the hyphen?

Like `0006` or even if integer value then `6`

I mean if there is by some way `EMP343-0006`, then I don't want the numbers before the hyphen `-` only numeric digits after the hyphen?

I am not good with preg, so I tried researching to find if its already been asked or something, there were many regular expressions questions, but none were the ones I want.

e-g

```
<?php
$string = "EMP2-0002";   
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string);
```

Now here if we see it returns all the digits, how to tweak it to return only digits after the hyphen character? Or is any other better solution available? Learning regular expressions seems little difficult.

Comment: `/(?<=-)\d+/` - any digits preceded by a hyphen. Simply `preg_match` it.

Comment: @deceze, Thankyou, but why negative score??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `-\d+` as the regular expression. I recommend graphical regex-editors like https://regex101.com/ for creating the expressions. It is much easier to see a (graphical) description what the expression does.

Edit: You can use groups:

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/-(?<number>\d+)/', 'EMP-0006', $matches);
```

You will get the number with accessing `$matches["number"]`. Then you don't have to replace parts of the string.

Comment: want the numeric value after the hyphen, your code is returning me only 1?
http://codepad.viper-7.com/BnCCac

Comment: `$returnValue` contains the index of the match (for the case you want to check if the number was found in the string).

As I sad, use `$matches["number"]` to get you number.

Comment: oops, my bad. sorry, i didn't see that before.. 
Many Thanks, It Works Awesome.. I don't understand how it is working but it is giving the result..

Comment: Great, you can look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/hY7bV9/1), at the right you can see a description what it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*-([0-9]+)$/', '$1', $string);
```

EDIT: you can also do it with `explode`:

```
$parts = explode('-', $string);
echo $parts[1];
```

Comment: tried your preg_replace, http://codepad.viper-7.com/5i25Kz
It returns all string except the hyphen, where as i want only digits after the hyphen not the whole string..